# How to add multiple datalayer parameters with for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, data-layer

**I have a datalayer with parameter "Price" which I want to add, e.g. 799 + 95 + 95.**

[image]

```
DigitalData[0].Cart.Items[0].Price
```

**Returns "799.00"**

Believe one could [JavaScript For Loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp%22optional%22) to achieve the subtraction of price that I'm looking for. But I'm not familiar how to type this scenario. Am I going towards the right direction? See below code?

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    DigitalData[0].Cart.Items[i].Price;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable to store the sum:

```
var sum = 0;
var items = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    sum += parseInt(items[i].Price);
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS THANKS CHRIS

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalPrice = 0;    
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
        var price = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items[i].Price;
        price = parseFloat(price);
        totalPrice += price;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var sum = DigitalData[0].Cart.Items.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + +a.Price;
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You where on the right way, this is the complete solution:

```
var sum=0;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    sum+=DigitalData[0].Cart.Items[i].Price;
}
```